No enum constant com.google.firebase.ErrorCode.UNIMPLEMENTED
[firebase-admin-7.0.0] No enum constant com.google.firebase.ErrorCode.UNIMPLEMENTED
The above error suddenly appeared. I checked the source code and found that there was no UNIMPLEMENTED object in ErrorCode. Does anyone know why?
I changed to version 9.2.0 but it still doesn't work. What else could be the problem?

I faced the same issue and changed
BatchResponse response = firebaseMessaging.sendMulticast(message);

to
BatchResponse response = firebaseMessaging.sendEachForMulticast(message);

also updated to version 9.3.0 and its working fine for me.

I tried it, it's ok, thank you very much

I tried this solution and it fixes it. So weird we didn't get any update from Google...? Anyway, @tian if this answer worked for you and us, feel free to mark the answer as approved :+1:

I also encountered this issue, as I used the firebase admin's sendMulticast method which has been deprecated in the latest SDK. I replaced it with sendEachForMulticast and did not encounter this problem again. The version I updated to is 9.2.0
